# How to run CopyFile, CopyURIs, MoveURIs methods of Nemo File Manager

Tags: dbus, gdbus

Under `org.Nemo.FileOperations` there are methods named: `CopyFile`, `CopyURIs`, `MoveURIs`. How can I use these methods (i am looking for cli commands which use dbus-send or any equivalent)?

[image: Nemo Dbus]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used D-Feet to get all the information you need so I assume you are struggling to find the correct command line syntax.

I personally find `busctl` the easier command line syntax.

An example of copying a file using `busctl` would be:

```
busctl --user call org.Nemo /org/Nemo org.Nemo.FileOperations CopyFile ssss file:$HOME/Downloads/test.txt test.txt file:$HOME/Downloads test2.txt
```

To do the same with `dbus-send` would be:

```
dbus-send --session --dest=org.Nemo --print-reply /org/Nemo org.Nemo.FileOperations.CopyFile string:file:$HOME/Downloads/test.txt string:file:test.txt string:file:$HOME/Downloads string:test3.txt
```

The `CopyURIs` and `MoveURIs` take an array of URIs as the first argument and a destination directory as the second argument. So an example of doing that with `busctl` would be:

```
busctl --user call org.Nemo /org/Nemo org.Nemo.FileOperations CopyURIs ass 2 file:$HOME/Downloads/test.txt file:$HOME/Downloads/test2.txt file:$HOME
```

The main thing with an array is that you have to include the number of how long the array is. In this example `2`

Comment: Can you please also add `CopyURIs` and `MoveURIs` syntax and also where is the documentation or how to find the syntax of the commands.

Comment: I also have a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/76597192/1772898

Comment: What documentation are you looking for?  `man dbus-send` and `man busctl` gives helpful information about the commands. Your screen grab of the Nemo API seems about the best documention I've seen

Comment: I was interested in copy paste of nemo because of https://askubuntu.com/a/1317394/598062 I mean mark now and copy or move later. Not understanding how to do it.